# If color is just reflection of light, then can someone's purple look red to others?

Tags: visible-light, biophysics, vision, perception

If color is just reflection of light, then can someone's purple look red to others? Can anyone lend me a hand here? I always wanted to know this.

Comment: Im kinda surprised by the fast downvotes. This is something I used to wonder when I was a kid. I like to think it's not that of a silly question, though it has little to do with physics...

Comment: Can you expand on this?  The answer is "yes" in like 4 or 5 different ways, but I don't know which one you are thinking of.  If you can write more than a sentence on the question, it should be easier to figure out what part of the journey from photons generated by a light to electrical impulses in the brain to qualia in the mind are applicable to your curiosity.

Comment: I always cringe when I read patently nonsensical statements such as "color is just reflection of light" the terms "color" and "reflection" describe two entirely different concepts belonging to disjoint categories, and that can therefore never be equated. Statements like these do not even begin to make any sense, regardless of what physics may say about color or reflection of light.

Comment: I don't see how the first part of the question has anything to do with the second part.

Comment: if a reflection hits someone differently, then they may see a different shade of color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to lookup "colorblind".

Colorblind people suffer from modifications of some of their retina's cells which are specialised in detecting colors. As colors are usually combinations of several colors, some of their content might not be interpreted the same way by their brain. They will not be able to distinguish some colors.
In this sense you may say we all see different colors. And we all are somewhat slightly colorblind.

Now, whether red seen by two persons with perfect vision is the same is a question for neuroscience. Not physics.

Comment: Ok, do they have SE for that?

Comment: You may try http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> *"Can someone's red look purple to others"*

Think in the following way:

If two people saw something different while looking at the same color, they would still have been taught the same word for it. Maybe somebody would have told and taught them both that this color is indeed **blue**. No matter if they actually saw the same thing or two different shades of color, they would both agree that it is blue the next time they see it.

One thing is the physics, another thing is perception. But a third thing is the invention of words. Those two people who maybe in reality see what is red and purple, have by someone else been taught that it is blue. They both teach the next generations that this is blue as well, because that's the name they learned for what they see. Unless they are growing up in two isolated societies, it continues like this.

It is never really compared, it is just named. Therefore the answer is **no**: someone's red cannot be another ones purple. If one sees red, the other one agrees that it's red - even if they see different things.

Answer (score 0):

In physics, there are lots of 'reflection' variants.  One of these is a reflection from a periodic structure (a grating, or an opal) that gives the familiar 
diffraction-jewel effect.   One sees different colors at different lighting and viewing
angles.  Similar effects like rainbows, oil slicks, prisms, will all
make it possible for different colors to be seen by different observers.

To those we can add doppler shifts (color changes due to relative velocity).

There are many everyday instances where all observers see the same color,
though: if you want to match a paint color, you can hold a variety of
paint samples up against your woodwork in daylight or other white light, and
get a good match.   Famously, one ought NOT try this matching under
random fluorescent or LED lighting.